# Como agregar validaciones a imagenes cargadas con Active Storage en rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo un problema a la hora de validar las imagenes cargadas.

EL objetivo es el siguiente, necesito que el usuario este obligado a cargar imagenes en formato PNG.

Para este proyecto solo cree un scaffold simple con los siguientes campos

firma:string, cargo:string, nombre:string

y 2 relaciones con active_storage

```
has_one_attached :signature
has_one_attached :sello
```

Estoy utilizando estos 2 metodos para validar la carga.

```
validate :acceptable_signature
validate :acceptable_sello

def acceptable_signature
  return unless signature.attached?
    
  acceptable_types = ["image/png"]
  unless acceptable_types.include?(signature.content_type)
    errors.add(:signature, "El Archivo debe ser PNG")
  end
end

def acceptable_sello
  return unless sello.attached?
    
  acceptable_types = ["image/png"]
  unless acceptable_types.include?(sello.content_type)
    errors.add(:sello, "El Archivo debe ser PNG")
  end
end
```

Mi controlador no tiene nada fuera de lo comun

```
  def create
    @signature = Signature.new(signature_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @signature.save
        format.html { redirect_to banco_inicio_path, notice: "Firma Creada con Éxito" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @signature }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @signature.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    if @signature.update(signature_params)
        redirect_to banco_inicio_path, notice: "Firma Actualizada con Éxito"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Las validaciones funcionan solo si el usuario carga un documento, pero si el usuario intenta cargar 1 archivo correcto y otro incorrecto, le arrojara rollback y no se cargara ninguno, como puedo evitar esto? ya que todos los campos en mi modelo son obligatorios y si el usuario ha llenado la data y sube un archivo incorrecto hace rollback y pierde todo lo que coloco.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo no hay problema con la validación, lo que quieres es no perder los datos ingresados en el formulario en caso que la validación capte un campo erróneo, ¿es eso o entendí mal? porque si es así, mejor comparte tu formulario y tu action `new`